# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.widget.TintManager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I am getting nuts with this case for whole day.

**This is MyPagerAdapter class**

```
/**
 * Created by ram on 5/9/16.
 */

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

import com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal.fragment.TabFragmentDetail;
import com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal.fragment.TabFragmentFollowUp;
import com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal.fragment.TabFragmentImaging;
import com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal.fragment.TabFragmentLabTest;

/**
 * Created by ronem on 2/9/16.
 */

public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    String[] tabs;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, String[] tabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.tabs = tabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return TabFragmentDetail.newInstance();
            case 1:
                return TabFragmentImaging.newInstance();
            case 2:
                return TabFragmentLabTest.newInstance();
            case 3:
                return TabFragmentFollowUp.newInstance();
            default:
                return null;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabs.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        return tabs[position];
    }

}
```

**This is pager_activity_layout.xml file for PagerActivity.java**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/all_news_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**This is my PagerActivity.java**

```
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;

import com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal.R;
import com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal.util.AppText;
import com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal.widget.adapter.MyPagerAdapter;

import java.util.Arrays;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

/**
 * Created by ram on 5/9/16.
 */
public class PagerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Bind(R.id.toolbar)
    Toolbar toolbar;
    @Bind(R.id.tab_layout)
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    @Bind(R.id.all_news_viewpager)
    ViewPager viewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pager_activity_layout);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        setToolbar();
        setViewPager();
        setTabLayout();//problem in this line

    }

    private void setToolbar() {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.admission_history_color)));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    private void setViewPager() {
        String[] array = AppText.Tab.getTabs(AppText.Tab.ADMINSSION_HISTORY);
        Log.i("array", Arrays.toString(array));

        MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), array);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void setTabLayout() {

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }


        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        ButterKnife.unbind(this);
    }
}
```

In above code whenever I comment the line with the function **setTabLayout();** in onCreate() method
view pager works fine but doesn't show any text in the tablayout.And when ever I un-comment **setTabLayout();** I got these errors

```
05-09 19:11:14.480 18543-18543/com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
05-09 19:11:14.480  18543-18543/com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal E/AndroidRuntime: Process:  com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal, PID: 18543 
05-09 19:11:14.480  18543-18543/com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal E/AndroidRuntime:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.widget.TintManager  
05-09 19:11:14.480 18543-18543/com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal  E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.<init>(TabLayout.java:1185)  
05-09 19:11:14.480 18543-18543/com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal  E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.createTabView(TabLayout.java:656)  
05-09 19:11:14.480 18543-18543/com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal  E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTabView(TabLayout.java:695)  
05-09 19:11:14.480 18543-18543/com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal  E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:386)  
05-09 19:11:14.480 18543-18543/com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal  E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:361)  
05-09 19:11:14.480 18543-18543/com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal  E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(TabLayout.java:645)  
05-09 19:11:14.480 18543-18543/com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal  E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(TabLayout.java:616)  
05-09 19:11:14.480 18543-18543/com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal  E/AndroidRuntime:     at  com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal.activity.PagerActivity.setTabLayout(PagerActivity.java:61)  
05-09 19:11:14.480 18543-18543/com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal  E/AndroidRuntime:     at  com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal.activity.PagerActivity.onCreate(PagerActivity.java:40)  
05-09 19:11:14.480 18543-18543/com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal  E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5322) 
05-09 19:11:14.480 18543-18543/com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal  E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)  
05-09 19:11:14.480 18543-18543/com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal  E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2303)  
05-09 19:11:14.480 18543-18543/com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal  E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)  
05-09 19:11:14.480 18543-18543/com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal  E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:166) 
05-09 19:11:14.480 18543-18543/com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal  E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)  
05-09 19:11:14.480 18543-18543/com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal  E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
05-09 19:11:14.480 18543-18543/com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal  E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
05-09 19:11:14.480 18543-18543/com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal  E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511) 
05-09 19:11:14.480 18543-18543/com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal  E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native  Method) 
05-09 19:11:14.480 18543-18543/com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal  E/AndroidRuntime:     at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
05-09 19:11:14.480  18543-18543/com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal E/AndroidRuntime:     at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)  
05-09 19:11:14.480 18543-18543/com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal  E/AndroidRuntime:     at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
05-09 19:11:14.480 18543-18543/com.bidhee.familyhealthnepal  E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I searched on net about this kind of error and most of the answers says the version should be same for the support libraries.
Here are my dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'

compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
```

Comment: try this dependenics......  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'

Comment: use build tool this  buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

Comment: thanks bro I tried this compile 'com.android.support:design:23.+' and it worked ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the version of dependencies 23.1.1 to 23.0.3

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yourapp.todo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'

}
```